# When creating a dictionary with values, the value is arbitrarily changed from False to True

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

It is necessary to form a dictionary as an argument of which a set of dictionaries. In these dictionaries there is a key named "reverse". This key is set to False by default. When adding a dictionary, the value of the "reverse" key I change depending on some conditions. But for some reason, in the general source vocabulary, the meaning of "reverse" changes only to Pravda.

Why does the meaning change arbitrarily and in what place?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

struct_state_devices = None
dict_gate = {"state_gate": {},
             "position": {"state": "", "stop": False},
             "reverse": False,
             }
test_list = [{"device_code": "1111", "reverse": False}, {"device_code": "2222", "reverse": True}]

if struct_state_devices is None:
    struct_state_devices = dict()
for dev in test_list:
    struct_state_devices[dev["device_code"]] = dict_gate  # добавление словаря устройства

print("before: " + str(struct_state_devices))

for dev in test_list:
    if dev["reverse"] is True:
        struct_state_devices[dev["device_code"]]["reverse"] = True
        # print(self.struct_state_devices[dev.device_code]['reverse'])
print("after: " + str(struct_state_devices))
```

Output:

```
before: {'1111': {'state_gate': {}, 'position': {'state': '', 'stop': False}, 'reverse': False}, '2222': {'state_gate': {}, 'position': {'state': '', 'stop': False}, 'reverse': False}}
after: {'1111': {'state_gate': {}, 'position': {'state': '', 'stop': False}, 'reverse': True}, '2222': {'state_gate': {}, 'position': {'state': '', 'stop': False}, 'reverse': True}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the object `dict_gate` to your dict keys `struct_state_devices[dev['device_code']]`. When you change a value inside that object to some other value, you're changing it for all others as well.

Try this instead:

```py
for dev in test_list:
    struct_state_devices[dev["device_code"]] = dict_gate.copy()
```

See what I mean:

```py
>>> for dev in test_list:
    struct_state_devices[dev['device_code']] = dict_gate

>>> id(dict_gate)
1267141041832
>>> id(struct_state_devices['1111'])
1267141041832

>>> for dev in test_list:
    struct_state_devices[dev['device_code']] = dict_gate.copy()

>>> id(struct_state_devices['1111'])
1267141285912
>>> id(struct_state_devices['2222'])
1267141286232
```

Note the ID when using `dict_gate` instead of `dict_gate.copy()`